# Помогите определить назначение кода

Tags: php

Есть фрагмент кода в скрипте php. Подкскажите, что выполняется этим кодом? Все эти строки в отдельном файле `ss.php`:

```
<?php
include 'settings.php';

$val = text($_GET['val'],$db);
mysqli_query($db,"insert into nu3Dec (val) values ('$val')");
```

В `settings.php` происходит подключение к базе и указывается параметры скрипта. Функция text() там выглядит примерно так (из комментария):

```
function text( $text, $db) {
    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $text);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
    if( get_magic_quotes_gpc ()) {
        $text = stripslashes($text);
    }
    $text = trim($text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Найдите пожалуйста определение функции text() и приложите к вопросу.

Answer (score 3):

```
include 'settings.php'; // подключение модуля settings.php

$val = text($_GET['val'],$db);
// $_GET['val'] - смотрим url запроса к скрипту и берем из него значение val
// пример, http://site.ru/index.php?val=5
// в данном случае возьмем $_GET['val'] вернется 5
// если val нету будет null

// ту переменную которую получили и переменную $db передаем в функцию text()
// похоже, что $db это класс работы с базой данных в settings.php
// а text(), похоже тупо заносит в базу данных, параметр $_GET['val']

mysqli_query($db,"insert into nu3Dec (val) values ('$val')");
// ну тут просто, выполняется sql запрос к базе данных вида
// "insert into nu3Dec (val) values ('$val')"
// вставляется в таблицу nu3Dec тот самый val
```

PS Не забывайте экранировать запросы, ибо могут злоумышленники смогут вставлять иньекции в БД.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Karlos Derga, не за что :)

Answer (score 2):

Фрагмент обрабатывает GET-параметр `val`, поступающий через строку запроса, и вставляет в базу данных в таблицу `nu3Dec` новую запись с отфильтрованным функцией `text()` GET-параметром val.

Comment: Спасибо! Надеюсь, что это не вредоносный код.

Comment: Может, и вредоносный – надо убедиться, что делает неизвестная функция `text()` – вдруг, она как раз конструирует SQL-инъекцию?  : )

Comment: Я бы с радостью это сделал, но не силен в php совсем. Вам спасибо за исчерпывающую информацию.

Comment: Вот что-то есть такое: $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $text);
 $text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc ()){$text = stripslashes($text);}
 $text = trim($text);

 return $text;